How to Resolve "Ambiguous Column Reference" Error in PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL Function with INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?
I’m working on a PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL function that inserts a record into a table or updates it using ON CONFLICT. However, when I run the function, I encounter the following error:
[42702] ERROR: column reference "email" is ambiguous
Detail: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
Where: PL/pgSQL function create_email_verification(text, text, timestamp with time zone) line 3 at RETURN QUERY

Table structure:
CREATE TABLE email_verifications
(
    id          INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('email_verifications_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email       TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT unique_email UNIQUE,
    code        TEXT NOT NULL,
    expires_at  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    created_at  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    verified_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

Function:
create function create_email_verification(
    p_email text, 
    p_code text, 
    p_expires_at timestamp with time zone)

returns TABLE(
    id integer, 
    email text, 
    code text, 
    expires_at timestamp with time zone, 
    created_at timestamp with time zone
) language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        INSERT INTO email_verifications (email, code, expires_at)
        VALUES (p_email, p_code, p_expires_at)
        ON CONFLICT (email)
        DO UPDATE 
        SET
            code = EXCLUDED.code, 
            expires_at = EXCLUDED.expires_at
        RETURNING 
            email_verifications.id,
            email_verifications.email, 
            email_verifications.code,
            email_verifications.expires_at,
            email_verifications.created_at;
END;
$$;

Bonus information :
Running the same query outside the function works perfectly fine. For example, the following query executes without issues:
INSERT INTO email_verifications (email, code, expires_at)
VALUES ('test@example.com', '123456', NOW())
ON CONFLICT (email)
DO UPDATE 
SET
    code = EXCLUDED.code, 
    expires_at = EXCLUDED.expires_at
RETURNING id, email, code, expires_at, created_at;


Try ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_email instead of ON CONFLICT (email). Conflict_target can be one of: ( { index_column_name | ( index_expression )) or
ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name

Worked! Please answer below with explanation, it'll be accepted

For the underlying reason of why this happened read Variable substitution.

In function function create_email_verification there conflict between

column name email in table email_verifications
and
output result table column name email (returns TABLE(... email text...))

You can write ON CONFLICT clause using form ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT 
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_email

using constraint name from email TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT unique_email UNIQUE
thereby resolving the conflict in the name.
Or you can change name of column in returning table, if this possible
returns TABLE(
    ...
    email_x text, 
    ...
)

Try
create function create_email_verification(
    p_email text, 
    p_code text, 
    p_expires_at timestamp with time zone)

returns TABLE(
    id integer, 
    email text, 
    code text, 
    expires_at timestamp with time zone, 
    created_at timestamp with time zone
) language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        INSERT INTO email_verifications (email, code, expires_at)
        VALUES (p_email, p_code, p_expires_at)
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_email
        DO UPDATE 
        SET
            code = EXCLUDED.code, 
            expires_at = EXCLUDED.expires_at
        RETURNING 
            email_verifications.id,
            email_verifications.email, 
            email_verifications.code,
            email_verifications.expires_at,
            email_verifications.created_at;
END;
$$;

Update1.
The documentation on the link provided by @AdrianKlaver, shows how the names of tables, columns and variables are resolved.
Although the output result table is not explicitly specified in the query, it is implicitly present.
Let's look at an example:
There the use of columns from the output table does not make sense, we see that they are present and participate in name resolution, they can be quite referenced.
create function create_email_verification(
    p_email text, 
    p_code text, 
    p_expires_at timestamp with time zone)

returns TABLE(
    id integer, 
    email text, 
    code text, 
    expires_at timestamp with time zone, 
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    flag int
) language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        INSERT INTO email_verifications (email, code, expires_at)
        VALUES (p_email, p_code, p_expires_at)
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_email -- (email)
        DO UPDATE 
        SET
            -- code = EXCLUDED.code, 
            code = case when flag>0 then concat(EXCLUDED.code,'s') 
                   else concat(EXCLUDED.code,'x') end, 
            expires_at = EXCLUDED.expires_at
        RETURNING 
            email_verifications.id,
            email_verifications.email, 
            email_verifications.code,
            email_verifications.expires_at,
            email_verifications.created_at,
            flag;
END;
$$;

This is just an example. There is no practical point here, except for the example of name resolution.
Fiddle

The only thing i'm wondering is why the id gets increased when conflicted (even no record inserted) ?

You neglected to provide an explanation of why plpgsql sees this as a conflict. It is spelled out in the docs Variable substitution.

@blackkara, because sequences only advance and increment when they are called regardless of whether the calling statement succeeds or not. See CREATE SEQUENCE: Notes section for detailed explanation.

@AdrianKlaver As a beginner of postgresql, thanks

BTW, is it sth to be worried or OK to ignore this behaviour ?

@AdrianKlaver, thank you for helpfull comments and provided links.

A simple query like this, without any specific PL/pgSQL logic, can be written in SQL.  That will be faster.
